# Mapbox popups - How to query only the top-most layer when there are multiple overlapping layers?

Tags: mapbox, popup, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox map with one line layer and multiple point layers, as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Each has its own popup:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {

    if(!e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented) {
      e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    }

    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['photoData']
    });

    if (!features.length) {
        return;
    }

    var feature = features[0];

    var popupContent = '<img src="' + feature.properties.photo +'" style="width:100%;"> <p class="two" style="display:inline">' + feature.properties.text + '<br> <a href=" ' + feature.properties.photo + ' " target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Open photo in new window</a> </p>'

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, 0] })
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML(popupContent)
        .addTo(map);
});
```

When I click one of the overlapping points, it brings up popups for the top most point and the points/lines underneath it. How can I set it so that it only brings up the popup for the top-most feature?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check the layer you clicked on.

```
const handleMapClick = (e: MapEvent) => {
        const { features } = e;
    
        if (!features) {
          return;
        }
    
        const selectedFeature = features.find((feature) =>
          ['your-feature-1', 'your-feature-2'].includes(feature.layer.id),
        );
    
        if (!selectedFeature) {
          return;
        }
    
       // do your thing, for example open popup for layers given in selectedFeature
    }
```